# Storing in same id of database

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have this form to allow users to insert multiple phone types and multiple emails:

```
<div id="dynamicInput">
          <input type="text" name="mytype[]" placeholder="Phone Type"> <input type="text" name="myinputs[]" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');"></span>
<br>  </div><br>
```

And in the controller i have this piece of code:

```
    foreach($myinputs as $myinput)
    {
        $phone=new phone();
        $phone->secondary_phones=$myinput;
        $phone->id=$getlast;
        $phone->save();

    }

   foreach($mytype as $mytypes)
        {
                $phone=new phone();
                $phone->id=$getlast;
                $phone->secondary_phones_type=$mytypes;
                $phone->save();
        }
```

`$getlast` is the id from another table.

the problem here is phone types and phone numbers are added in the separate `phone_id`. what I want is respective phone type and phone number to be inserted in same `phone_id`. `phone_id` is auto increment primary key.
I have `secondary_phones` and `secondary_phones_type` as the database columns, I guess the problem is with saving in database differently for phone number and phone type.

Comment: You can't have the same id in a primary key. Primary keys HAVE to be unique.

Comment: @JonStirling i mean only the respective phone type and phone number to be inserted in same id. what i got is phone number in one id and phone type in another.

Comment: That makes all of no sense :P. Please provide your table schemas so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: you need to use `activeform` then you can load all data in model directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **same number of inputs** for *phone types* and *phone numbers*  than you can try it.

```
for($i=0;$i<$myinputs.length;$i++)
{
  $phone=new phone();
  $phone->secondary_phones=$myinputs[$i];
  $phone->secondary_phones_type=$mytype[$i];
  $phone->id=$getlast;
  $phone->save();
}
```

Comment: It displayed Use of undefined constant length.